# Getting error when launching iOS device in appium

Tags: appium

I have Xcode 8.2 version. I wrote the code in the eclipse and trying to run. I was able to install the ipa file but while trying to open the app, its not opening. Please find my code below -

```
package com.sampleiOS.com.sampleiOS;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;

//import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;




/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest 
{
    //public WebDriver driver;
    public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    /**
     * @return 
     * @return 
     * @return the suite of tests being tested
     * @throws MalformedURLException 
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    @Test
    public void Rijo() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
    {

        AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService
                .buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                        .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/opt/node/bin/node"))
                        .withAppiumJS(new File(
                                "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js")));
                        //.withLogFile(new File("AppiumServerLogs/logs.txt")));
        service.start();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Ipod");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.3");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "4319165xxxxx");
       capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/rijom/Downloads/xx.ipa");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");

        driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    }
}
```

Please find appium console log below -

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /private/var/folders/hh/qx4s0ttd3zg3fn0w7g10hgt00000gs/T/testng-eclipse--1535528232/testng-customsuite.xml

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.0 (REV 0f37e2943bba265b42bb2087ea24b86dcc614c35)
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.6.0"...
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 23 ms - 121 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/rijom/Downloads/RSSFeedReader.ipa","automationName":"XCUITest","udid":"43191654cb4d510f9f3e75a1577fef3bff459859","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"Ipod","platformVersion":"9.3"}}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/Users/rijom/Downl...
[Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   app: '/Users/rijom/Downloads/RSSFeedReader.ipa'
[Appium]   automationName: 'XCUITest'
[Appium]   udid: '43191654cb4d510f9f3e75a1577fef3bff459859'
[Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'Ipod'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '9.3'
[debug] [XCUITest] XCUITestDriver version: 2.0.26
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: ed58e7cb-1b46-42ca-aacf-c5edc9289573
[debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to '8.2'
[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '10.2'
[debug] [XCUITest] Available devices: 43191654cb4d510f9f3e75a1577fef3bff459859
[debug] [XCUITest] Creating iDevice object with udid 43191654cb4d510f9f3e75a1577fef3bff459859
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: '43191654cb4d510f9f3e75a1577fef3bff459859', real device: true
[BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/rijom/Downloads/RSSFeedReader.ipa'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Copying local zip to tmp dir
[debug] [BaseDriver] Unzipping /var/folders/hh/qx4s0ttd3zg3fn0w7g10hgt00000gs/T/201711-76306-k3wipf.ft3wok1emi/appium-app.zip
[debug] [BaseDriver] Testing zip archive: /var/folders/hh/qx4s0ttd3zg3fn0w7g10hgt00000gs/T/201711-76306-k3wipf.ft3wok1emi/appium-app.zip
[BaseDriver] Unzipped local app to '/var/folders/hh/qx4s0ttd3zg3fn0w7g10hgt00000gs/T/201711-76306-k3wipf.ft3wok1emi/Payload/RSSFeedReader.app'
[debug] [XCUITest] Checking whether app is actually present
[debug] [ios-app-utils] Getting bundle ID from app
[debug] [iOSLog] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog
[debug] [iOSLog] Found idevicesyslog: '/usr/local/bin/idevicesyslog'
[XCUITest] Setting up real device
[debug] [XCUITest] Stdout from app isInstalled check: [....] Waiting for iOS device to be connected
[....] Using iPod Touch 5G 'Ipod' (43191654cb4d510f9f3e75a1577fef3bff459859).
true

[debug] [XCUITest] App is installed.
[debug] [XCUITest] Full reset not requested. No need to install.
[XCUITest] Using default agent: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj
[XCUITest] Using default bootstrap: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent
[XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[debug] [XCUITest] Carthage found: /usr/local/bin/carthage
[debug] [XCUITest] Beginning test with command '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/bin/run-xcodebuild.sh --project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj --scheme WebDriverAgentRunner --destination id=43191654cb4d510f9f3e75a1577fef3bff459859' in directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
[XCUITest] Waiting for WebDriverAgent to start on device
[debug] [XCUITest] Log file for xcodebuild test: /Users/rijom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/B8534D7A-50CD-4B8A-8AD6-382B80BC7B84/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2017-02-01_154328-QrQMw9.log
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Feb  1 15:43:53 Ipod XCTRunner[493] <Warning>: Running tests...
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Feb  1 15:43:55 Ipod XCTRunner[493] <Warning>: Continuing to run tests in the background with task ID 1
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Feb  1 15:43:56 Ipod XCTRunner[493] <Warning>: Built at Feb  1 2017 15:43:37
[XCUITest] Detected that WebDriverAgent is running at url 'http://192.168.2.112:8100'
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Feb  1 15:43:57 Ipod XCTRunner[493] <Warning>: ServerURLHere->http://192.168.2.112:8100<-ServerURLHere
[XCUITest] WebDriverAgent started at url 'http://192.168.2.112:8100'
[debug] [XCUITest] Starting iproxy to forward traffic from local port 8100 to device port 8100 over USB
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Feb  1 15:43:57 Ipod XCTRunner[493] <Warning>: Listening on USB
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Feb  1 15:43:57 Ipod SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
[debug] [iProxy] bind(): Address already in use
[debug] [iProxy] Error creating socket: Address already in use
[XCUITest] Error: iproxy exited with code '208'
    at SubProcess.<anonymous> (lib/webdriveragent.js:378:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at SubProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (lib/teen_process.js:191:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
 Error: iproxy exited with code '208'
    at SubProcess.<anonymous> (lib/webdriveragent.js:378:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at SubProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (lib/teen_process.js:191:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
[debug] [XCUITest] Running ios real device reset flow
[debug] [XCUITest] Resetting simulator
[debug] [iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: iproxy exited with code '208'
    at SubProcess.<anonymous> (lib/webdriveragent.js:378:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at SubProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (lib/teen_process.js:191:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 71554 ms - 166 
FAILED: Rijo
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: iproxy exited with code '208' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 71.82 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'Suvarnaratnas-Mac-mini.local', ip: '192.168.3.135', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:77)
    at com.sampleiOS.com.sampleiOS.AppTest.Rijo(AppTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter@6a5fc7f7: 85 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@2d209079: 89 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@2133c8f8: 14 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@d041cf: 12 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@7a79be86: 44 ms
```

I had updated the WebDriverAgentLib with my app Team and certificates also then its creating an new app as webDriverAgent but not opening my app. Could you help me how to open the app?

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6996#issuecomment-278349789

Answer (score 0):

If there is a rogue iproxy session you can kill it by executing

```
ps -ax|grep -i "iproxy"|grep -v grep|awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}'|sh
```

on the command line.

Comment: Hi Jasmine
I am getting this response for above command sh: line 1: kill: (440) - Operation not permitted.Tried with sudo also then also same response

Answer (score 0):

iProxy is not exited, find the port and kill it.
To find the port:

```
lsof -i -n -P | grep 8100
```

To kill:

```
kill -9 PORT_NUMBER
```

copy this in terminal

```
export USE_PORT=8100
```

For real device, reconnect iOS cable and try running the code.